# Why doesn't this alter after insert statement work?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure with dynamic sql that i have embedded as below:

```
 delete from #temp_table
 begin tran
         set @sql = 'select * into #temp_table from sometable'
         exec (@sql)

commit tran

begin
set @sql = 'alter table #temp_table add column1 float'
exec(@sql)
end

 update #temp_table 
 set column1 = column1*100

select *
into Primary_Table
from  #temp_table
```

However, I noticed that all the statements work but the alter does not. When run the procedure, I get an error message: "Invalid Column name column1"

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Realized I didn't mention that the first insert is a dynamic sql as well. Updated it.

Alternate approach tried but throws same error:

```
      delete from #temp_table
       begin tran
         set @sql = 'select * into #temp_table from sometable'
         exec (@sql)
       commit tran
       alter table #temp_table add column1 float
       update #temp_table set column1 = column1*100
```

Comment: The compiler has no idea what's in your dynamic sql. Also your begin/commit tran seem superfluous and unnecessary. You'll need to insert GO commands (batch delimiters) to get past the compiler thinking there is no such column.

Comment: Got it thanks. Will remove the begin/commit tran

Comment: Your first insert isn't inserting anything - there's no from clause. It should be something like "select * into #temp_table from some_other_table"

Comment: @Mike - yes ofcourse. It is just an example. Could as well be select 1 into #temp_table. The original script is dynamic with 265 columns.

Comment: @Bee, no it couldn't. The constants like `1` have to be aliased in the select list, `select 1 as column_name into #temp_table`.

Comment: But yes ofcourse, however, the issue is really not with the insert. I see the table loaded with all the data. issue is with the alter and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local temporary tables exhibit something like dynamic scope. When you create a local temporary table inside a call to `exec` it goes out of scope and existence on the return from `exec`.

```
EXEC (N'create table #x (c int)')
GO
SELECT * FROM #x
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   Invalid object name '#x'.

The select is parsed after the dynamic SQL to create `#x` is ran. But `#x` is not there because dropped on exit from `exec`.

**Update**

Depending on the situation there are different ways to work around the issue.

1. Put everything into the same string:

   ```
   DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT 1 AS source INTO #table_name;
       ALTER TABLE #table_name ADD TARGET float;
       UPDATE #table_name SET Target = 100 * source;';
   EXEC (@Sql);
   ```
2. Create the table ahead of the dynamic sql that populates it.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #table_name (source INT);
   EXEC (N'insert into #table_name (source) select 1;');
   ALTER TABLE #table_name ADD target FLOAT;
   UPDATE #table_name SET target = 100 * source;
   ```

In this option, the `alter table` statement can be removed by adding the additional column to the `create table` statement.' Note also that the `alter table` and `update` statements *could* be in separate invocations of dynamic SQL, if that was beneficial to your context.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the right approach in that case? If I have to use dynamic sql to insert into a temp table, alter the table and update the added columns with values from originally created temp table?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) It should be ALTER TABLE #temp... Not ALTER #temp.
>
> 2) Even if #1 weren't an issue, you're adding column1, as a NULLable column with no default value and, in the next statement setting it's value to itself * 100...
>   NULL * 100 = NULL
>
> 3) Why are you using dynamic sql to alter the #temp table? It can just as easily be done with a regular ALTER TABLE script... or, better yet, can be included in the original table definition.

Comment: For #1, surely it is a typo. For #2, that is how I had initially run the script, without the dynamic sql for alter and update. But it errored out with an "invalid column" - figured it needed to be wrapped in dynamic as well and re-ran it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the #temp_table reference in the outer batch is a different temp table than the one created in dynamic SQL.  Consider:

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists sometable
drop table if exists #temp_table
go

create table sometable(id int, a int)

create table #temp_table(id int, b int)

exec( 'select * into #temp_table from sometable; select * from #temp_table;' )
select * from #temp_table
```

Outputs

```
id          a
----------- -----------

(0 rows affected)

id          b
----------- -----------

(0 rows affected)
```

A temp table created in a nested batch is scoped to the nested batch and automatically dropped after.  A "nested batch" is either a dynamic SQL query or a stored procedure.  This behavior is explained here [CREATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql), but it only mentions stored procedures.  Dynamic SQL behaves the same.

If you create the temp table in a top level batch, you can access it in dynamic SQL, you just can't create a *new* temp table in dynamic SQL and see it in the outer batch or in subsequent same-level dynamic SQL.  So try to use INSERT INTO instead of SELECT INTO.

Comment: aah..Thanks, understood. Was hoping to create a table up in front since it spans 300 columns - guess don't have any other option.